# Problem with old tokens of Huawei PUSH kit

Tags: push-notification, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I am using the Huawei Push Toolkit to send push messages to customers. There is a mechanism where the push tokens of each device are often refreshed, so a token used right now might be different than a token used, say, a day ago.

The issue was that if we try to send a push to a token that was valid only yesterday, the response is:

{ "code": "80000000"
"msg": "Success",
"requestId": "161615569495608835000107"
}

However, naturally, the device didn't receive the push because it was in the meantime refreshed. If sending it to the most up-to-date push token, the response is still the same and the device does get the message.

Why didn't the API return a different response, say, the error code `80300007` (all tokens invalid) in the first scenario? This is consistently replicated even for tokens older than 1 day (tested as far back as a 25 days old token).

[reference](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/https-send-api-0000001050986197-V5#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001124288117__section13968115715131)

The endpoints tested were: https://push-api.cloud.huawei.com/v2/.../messages:send

and https://push-api.cloud.huawei.com/v1/.../messages:send

Both have the same behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The situation you experience with the device token is normal for the Push server and it is about the information flow and the return value is just a presentation of the current node. To explain briefly 1. The Access Token is used only for the authentication interface. If the AT does not expire after the authentication succeeds, no error is reported. 2. The server pushes messages through the Push interface. If success:80000000 is returned, the Huawei Push server has received the messages, but this does not mean that the messages can be pushed to the terminal.

Comment: When setting up receipts, one will be notified of failed delivery attempts.